# helm - overwrite all values in a specific key in the values files

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have 2 values files with many entries. I'd like to overwrite all entries for a specific key using - "helm template . -f values.yaml -f values-prod.yaml'

For example:

```
values.yaml

key:
  a: 1
  b: 2
  c: 3

key2:
  d: 4
  f: 5
```

```
values-prod.yaml

key:
 c: 33
```

I'd like the generated values.yaml to be:

```
key:
  c: 33

key2:
  d: 4
  f: 5
```

I understand I can setup a value of a key to null for all the sub-keys I want to remove and that would remove it, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not.  If you think there's a possibility you will want the value to be unset in some or many environments, the best approach is to not provide a default value for it in your chart's `values.yaml` file.

```yaml
# values.yaml
key:
  c: 3
```

```yaml
# values-dev.yaml
key:
  a: 1
```

```yaml
# values-prod.yaml
key:
  c: 33
```

You're probably aware of the Helm `default` template function and normal `if` conditionals, but you can also provide these defaults in code, which on the one hand lets you compute them but on the other can make them be harder to override.

```yaml
# Use `key2.c` if it's set, but `key.c` otherwise
data:
  c: {{ .Values.key2.c | default .Values.key.c | default "no c value" | quote }}
```

(If the `values.yaml` file is the one in your Helm chart, next to the `Chart.yaml` file, Helm includes it automatically and at the first position in the option list, and you do not need a `helm install -f values.yaml` option.)